# Ignore any number in the tenth position in Open Offic Calc

Tags: openoffice-calc

I am trying to right a script for a current project but I need it to note display the number in the tenth position.

For example,

`A1 = 9`
`A2 = 3`

`=SUM(A1+A2)`

Would be
12

How ever how can I get it to display only 2?
The numbers will change with each entry. Sometimes it could be 9+45= 54 however I would want it to display only 4. Not sure how I would go about making it take away the number only in the tenth position.

Comment: Tens position? Or ones position?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can trasnform number to string then take last number. Something like this:

```
C1 = SUM(A1 + A2)
RIGHT(TEXT(C1,0),1)
```

The result is
`2`

Answer (score 2):

You probably want something like:

```
=MOD(A1+A2,10)
```

Though I believe OpenCalc will use the semicolon as a parameter delimiter.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the `Units` position, not the `Tens`. The `Units` is always the furthest right character so just extract it right from there. No need to convert to string first

```
=RIGHT(SUM(A1:A2),1)
```